# ListView and MySQL in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, wpf, listview

I am trying to do an editable ListView in WPF with a List View, so I found this tutorial with full code on windowsclient.net: http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=83530

And It works great! But, I need it to connect to a remote mysql database on my hosts server, not a local database. Can this be done? Any help at all is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'll explain you for example you need to display the list of data about Person
you have the following class

```
   public class Person
   {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
   }
```

If you need you can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to be able to bind for propeties of class Person
 also you should use the ObservableCollection (you need to add the reference WindowsBase assembly)

```
ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

this persons collection you will use to bind to the ListView

also you need to create the an mapper class for map data from DataSet with data from MySQL into 
the class Person. I think this is better way to bind the strngly typed collection, but therefore you
can use this method [Bind to an ADO.NET Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752057.aspx)

Comment: :O- @Serghei, thanks so much for taking the time to explain it for me. That was very helpful. I am checking out the link now. :-)

Comment: If this answer solve your problem mark it as answered this will help other people to find answer quickly

Answer (score 0):

To connect to MySQL data base you should use the [MySQL connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net)

and you will be able to access the data in you code using the ADO.NET technology

Comment: Thanks. I've always used MySQL Connector, in WinForms, and that's how I want to use it in WPF. BUT, I don't know how to bind data from a remote database to a listview control in WPF it's way different in WPF.